# Java won't connect to SQL Server

Tags: java, database, userid

I'm trying to retrieve data from a database using Netbeans 7.

```
try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LibraryApp","app","nbuser");
        String sql ="select* from Member";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            //String name = rs.getString("MAKE");
            int a = rs.getInt("member_id");
            jComboBox1.addItem(a);
        }
    }

        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

About my database:
Schema : APP
userid: nbuser
password: password

I always get this error message java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection authentication failure occurred. Reason: userid or password invalid.

Thanks.

Comment: what about connection url like this `private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true;user=me;password=mine";`

Comment: Still getting the same message error java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection authentication failure occurred. Reason: userid or password invalid.